# How to build a better SDN Controller for this problem?

Tags: python, ubuntu, sdn, mininet, ryu

I'm trying to solve this problem for a homework:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uf5nJ.jpg

I have a Mininet network with 3 AP and 2 Stations. One station is fixed and the other is a drone that can randomly move freely on the x axis and on a limited range on the y axis. 
The APs are controlled by a remote controller, who decides on which one of the AP3's ports the traffic between STA1 and STA2 has to be forwarded to.
So for a few seconds, when STA2 changes his AP (from AP1 to AP2 or viceversa), STA1 can't reach it.

The basic controller just checks every 5 seconds if he needs to change the forwarding port. This causes around 30% packet loss if we ping from STA1 to STA2 every 0.3 seconds for 15 mins.
Increasing the timeout is not an option, given the fact that it would cause more overhead.

Nothing comes to my mind to make it better, if you have any suggestion please help.